# Enable access to location Windows 8 app (Geolocator)

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using Geolocator. So I have async method OnPositionChanged() and everything should be good. But I have problem with getting access to location. If I use Windows 8 Sample Geolocation App everything works ok. I have Message that app use location I give access and it works, but in my application this message not appears and status of Geolocator is Disabled. How can I give access to location to my app programmatically?

Comment: take a look at the manifest file and the "capabilities" tab, add the "Location" capability

Comment: The manifest file is in the root of your Store project, it is called "Package.appxmanifest"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to Windows Phone, using a location requires you as a developer, to explicitly declare that your application will require access to the location API. This is set in the application manifest. In a Solution explorer, look for Package.appmanifest item and double click on it to open – the manifest properties window will open.

Click on the Capabilities tab. Check Location capability (just under it).
[image: Geolocation]

Comment: Bingo. I don't know why this doesn't thrown an exception. I think the other capabilities do (like if you forget to check the Document Library and then try to access it). This one fails more silently, especially if you're not checking status, and it's caught me a few times too.

Comment: Do you know, how to enable geolocalization for application wrote on windows7? Old configuration do not have manifest file.